# Select All column data as upper

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, uppercase

**Select All column data as upper**

at the moment i am using `upper(columnname) as 'xyz'` by this i am **losing col name** that i dont want

and my requirement is `select col1,col2,col3,col4 from xyz table`

i am looking for a method that can make all 4 col to upper in single syntax without losing col name

eg : `select Upper(col1,col2,col3,col4) from xyz table`

Comment: use `select upper(colname) as colname`

Comment: `upper(columnname) as 'xyz'` is invalid (standard) SQL. Identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes (`as "xyz"`). Single quotes (`'`) are for string constants only.

Comment: my query is running fine but i have 20 columns name so in that case i have to write 20 time upper and give alias name

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Why do you have 20 columns?

Comment: its just my database structures

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @columnName varchar(25)
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
declare @tableName as nvarchar(30)
set @tableName = 'YOURTABLE'
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
where c.object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name  = @tableName )


OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT

FROM @cursor INTO @columnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


set @sql = 'update YOURTABLE set '+ @columnName +' =   upper(' + @columnName + ') where YOURTABLE.'+@columnName+' = YOURTABLE.'+ @columnName+''
EXEC(@sql)


FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @columnName
END

CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

UPDATE: You have to update all of your column so that all of them will be turned into upper case

Take note : 
PLEASE BACKUP YOUR TABLE BEFORE PROCEEDING
Change YOURTABLE into your table name

Comment: If this is the solution, please mark it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  select UPPER(col1) AS Col1,UPPER(col2) AS col2,UPPER(col3) as
  col3,UPPER(col4 ) as col4 from xyz table
```